# spilling over a new node in a binary tree with the modified preoder tree traversal algorithm

Tags: php, binary-tree

I want to implement binary tree placement in an MlM app using php,

terms used:

referrer, upline, downline

A referrer will only be the upline of the first 2 reffered, additional referrals will be spilled over to the binary tree to fill any available space, from left to right

Example:

1. "A" refers "B and "C" and "D",
2. "B" and "C" and placed as downlines of "A",
3. "C" is then spilled over to the next available space.
4. in this case on the left of "B" , since does not have any downline yet

   ```
     A
     /\
    /  \
   B    C
   ```

   /
     D

Assuming every referrer brings in only 2 people, I ama able to automatically add it into the table using modified preorder tree traversal algorithm,

but my challenge is identifying the next available space on the table (sequentially) to add the spill over from referrer who already has 2 downlines.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved the problem myself.

```
//traverse the network binary tree to fetch the next available upline to place the user under
    function get_next_free_upline($pref, $sponsor_id)
    {

        $ref_id = $sponsor_id;
        $get_next = TRUE;

        $level = 1;
        $lft = $this->get_pointers($ref_id, 'lft');
        $rgt = $this->get_pointers($ref_id, 'rgt');
        $offset = $this->get_offset($lft, $rgt);

        while ($get_next !== FALSE) 
        {               
            $query = $this->db->query
            ('  SELECT node.*, (COUNT(parent.upline_id) - ' . $offset . ') AS level
                FROM tree AS node
                CROSS JOIN tree AS parent
                WHERE (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt AND 
                 node.lft > ' . $lft .' AND node.rgt < ' . $rgt . ')
                GROUP BY node.id    
                having level = ' . $level . '
                ORDER BY node.lft           
            ');


            $result = $query->result();

            //check if this upline has less than 2 downlines
            //if yes, assign the user_id to upline and return
            if ($query->num_rows() < 2)
            {
                $upline_id = $sponsor_id;
                $get_next = FALSE;
            }
            else
            {   //loop through all members under the current sponsor id 
                //to know where to spill over the referred member
                foreach ($result as $row):  



                    $sponsor_id = $row->id;

                    //check all occurences of this level member as an upline            
                    $this->db->select('*');
                    $this->db->from('tree');
                    $this->db->where('upline_id', $sponsor_id);

                    $inner_query = $this->db->get();

                    if ($inner_query->num_rows() < 2)
                    {
                        $upline_id = $sponsor_id;
                        $get_next = FALSE;
                        break;
                    }           
                endforeach; 

                //increase the level number and loop back               
                $level  = $level + 1;
                $get_next = TRUE;   
            }               
        }           
            return $upline_id;
    }
```